# Why there is an error with the resource controller?

Tags: laravel

I have an Admin folder with UserController (resource) inside

```
--Controllers
    --Admin
      -- UserController.php
```

In web.php I have the following routes:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController;


    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function (){
            Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
            Route::resource('user', UserController::class);
   });
```

UserController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{ 
    public function index()
    {
       return view('admin.user.index');
    }
}
```

When I try to go to admin/user I get an error

```
Target class [Admin\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController] does not exist.
```

I will be grateful for the hint.

Comment: can you show controller code.need to see namespace

Comment: @drew.p have you tried doing a dump autoload? `php artisan dump-autoload`

Comment: I tried. Rout starts when I transfer it from a group with the prefix 'admin' and change it as follows `Route::resource('admin/users', UserController::class);`. But why doesn't it work in a group with a prefix ??.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the namespace to Admin so it adds it in the base namespace. Just remove the namespace. It should work.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function (){
            Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
            Route::resource('user', UserController::class);
});
```